# How can I set up my Heroku-hosted Nodejs server to receive data from an IoT device using GPRS?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, ip, gprs

I am configuring an IoT device with GPRS. I have already procurred the IoT simcards from my GPRS provider. One of the requirements from the Concentrator Software(used for configuring the IoT device) is to provide an IP address and port number of my server which is supposed to receive the data.The server is designed using Express.js and hosted in Heroku. I understand that Heroku does not provide an IP address for the apps running on it. How can I sort out this?

Our initial assumption was that the data from the IoT device should be relayed to the GPRS service provider. Once there,the data should be relayed to our custom callback URLS(api endpoint) just like Sigfox.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.